# c# Отправка Post запроса c параметрами и переход по ссылке

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Есть сайт, с которого будут приобритаться билеты, есть пример от банка, по какому принципу отправлять данные для осуществления покупки.
Однако, пример предпологает переход сразу по ссылке, куда передаются параметры.

```html
<form action="https://www.банк.com/МетодНачалаОплаты" METHOD="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="MerchantLogin" value="000000">
        <input type="hidden" name="RequestCurrCode" value="000">
        <input type="hidden" name="RequestSum" value="запрашиваемая сумма">
        <input type="hidden" name="nivid" value="УникальныйНомерНомерПлатежа">
        <input type="hidden" name="Desc" value="Описание покупки">
        <input type="hidden" name="istest" value=1><!--тестовый платеж -->
        <input type="hidden" name="SignatureValue" value="сигнатура данных.Вычисляется по принципу из док-ции">
        <div class="ml-auto2">
            <input type="submit" @onclick="()=>InitStructForRequestPay()" class="btn btn-danger px-5" name="GoPay" value="Оплатить">
        </div>
</form>
```

Каким способом можно заменить данную форму?
Пробывал подобный способ, ответ получаю успешно, однако, получаю результат в текстовом виде.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
          { "MerchantLogin", "000000" },
          { "RequestCurrCode", "000" },
          { "RequestSum", "35"},
          { "nivid", "12345" },
          { "Desc", "Тестовая покупка" },
          { "istest", "1" },
          { "SignatureValue", SignatureValue }
      };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.банк.com/МетодНачалаОплаты", content);

     responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Нужно переходить по этой ссылке пользователю, т.к. далее ввод данных уже на сайте банка данных карты и т.п.
Прошу, не пинайте- новичок в этом, потому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Данную форму отправляет не инпут, а JS скрипт, метод InitStructForRequestPay, нужно смотреть, что там на самом деле и в каком формате отправляется серверу и HTML код здесь не поможет. Анализируйте трафик, передаваемый на сервер, изучайте какие данные в запросе и HTTP заголовки передаются. _получаю результат в текстовом виде_ - а в каком виде надо?

Comment: @aepot Это не так. Метод который вы упоминаете, заполняет структуру, по нажатию на кнопку, одновременно отправляя данные в банк.Все написано на шарпе и HTML.

Comment: Как я написал, установка параметров, отправка запроса и переход по этой же ссылке, куда мы устанавливали параметры.По сути, аналог формы, что на HTML, только кодом C#.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Ну может кто-то другой вам поможет. Если вы хотите отправить юзеру переадресацию, читайте заголовок Location из ответа, и отдавайте тот же статус и тот же заголовок клиенту, которые получили от запроса. `response.Headers.Loсation` или как-то так, смотрите в отладчик. Куки скорее всего тоже придется пробросить, в этом месте не все так просто, так как сами куки должен выставлять хост отправителя. Поэтому вероятно C# не поможет, придется все равно этот запрос отправлять со стороны браузера, пусть даже средствами JS. То есть то что вы хотите на C#, надо на JS писать.

Comment: Теги вод вопросом странные, советую изучить разницу между ASP, ASP.NET и ASP.NET Core, и поправить тег. А то тег ASP говорит о том, что вы пишете на VBScript (описание тега asp почитайте), а в посте C#, странно.

Comment: Виноват, поправил.

Comment: Не до конца понял, что нужно. Но если вы хотите что бы пользователь на вашем сайте вводил данные своей карты,  то это не получится из-за соображений безопасности. Не ясно также на какой из архитектур вы делаете приложение. Это MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor-Server или Blazor-WebAssembly?  Вот [видео](https://youtu.be/-PW1L5pygqY) из курса по ASP.NET Core MVC, где есть раздел о настройке платежной системы для интернет магазина.  Если вы делаете на Blazor, то вот [видео](https://youtu.be/YdUuukDpkWg) по его основам.